# void function parameter and overload resolution/template argument deduction

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I am developing a system where users register their functions with a framework that calls the functions on the users' behalf.  The framework accepts user functions that have at least one function parameter, which helps discourage functions with too many side effects.  The number of input parameters to a function is thus checked at compile time.  My code for getting the number of input parameters is simple:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename... Args>
constexpr std::size_t number_input_parameters(R (*)(Args...)) { return sizeof...(Args); }
```

and then using it:

```cpp
int no_parameters() {} // would be rejected by the framework
static_assert(number_input_parameters(no_parameters) == 0);
```

While developing the code, I was worried about functions that have `void` parameters:

```cpp
int still_no_parameters(void) {} // framework should also reject this
```

but to my delight, the above implementation of `number_of_parameters` gives the right answer (using Clang 15 and GCC 12):

```
static_assert(number_input_parameters(still_no_parameters) == 0);
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/Taeox1rMq.

So clearly a function with a type `R(void)` is correctly interpreted by the compiler as having type `R()`.  The link above also shows this to be true without using templates.

**The question:** In what way does the C++(20) standard somehow specify that a `void` function parameter should be ignored?  I've looked in various places and been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In what way does the C++(20) standard somehow specify that a void function parameter should be ignored?

From https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct-4 :

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type void is equivalent to an empty parameter list.

Comment: Wow, that was uber fast @KamilCuk.  Thanks.